# Convert pandas hierarchical DataFrame to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that contains hierarchical elements from my database. `parent_id` columns tells me to what parent each child belongs.
I would like to generate a nested JSON from this DataFrame (see section 3 for needed format). I tried many things, but I am mainly stuck on the `_children` list field in each parent, which should contain all its children. Any help is more than welcome, Thanks!

**1. pandas DataFrame (WHAT I HAVE)**

```
parent_id    child_id   level
125582       214659     1
125582       214633     1
125582       214263     1
214263       131673     2
214263       125579     2
214263       125578     2
214263       172670     2
214263       214266     2
214266       216675     3
214266       216671     3
172670       172669     3
172670       174777     3
172670       207661     3
207661       216529     4
207661       223884     4
223884       223885     5
223885       229186     6
229186       219062     7
229186       222243     7
and so on...
```

**2. DataFrame logic**

```
125582 (level 0 - root)
--214659 (level 1)
--214633 (level 1)
--214263 (level 1)
----131673 (level 2)
----125579 (level 2)
----125578 (level 2)
----172670 (level 2)
------172669 (level 3)
------174777 (level 3)
------207661 (level 3)
--------216529 (level 4)
--------223884 (level 4)
----------223885 (level 5)
------------229186 (level 6)
--------------219062 (level 7)    
--------------222243 (level 7)
----214266 (level 2)
------216675 (level 3)
------216671 (level 3)
and so on...
```

**3. JSON (WHAT I NEED)**

```
[
    {id: 125582, level: 0, "_children": [
        {id: 214659, level: 1},
        {id: 214633, level: 1},
        {id: 214263, level: 1, "_children": [
            {id: 131673, level: 2},
            {id: 125579, level: 2},
            {id: 125578, level: 2},
            {id: 172670, level: 2, "_children": [
                {id: 172669, level: 3},
                {id: 174777, level: 3},
                {id: 207661, level: 3, "_children": [
                    {id: 216529, level: 4},
                    {id: 223884, level: 4, "_children": [
                        {id: 223885, level: 5, "_children": [
                            {id: 229186, level: 6, "_children": [
                                {id: 219062, level: 7},
                                {id: 222243, level: 7}
                            ]}
                        ]}
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]},
            {id: 214266, level: 2, "_children": [
                {id: 216675, level: 3},
                {id: 216671, level: 3}
            ]}
        ]},
        and so on...
    ]}
]
```

Comment: Anyone any idea? :(

Comment: This is a very vague question... are you trying to do this one time? Repetitively? Where are you getting the data from?
This is a simple programming problem where you iterate through the list and build the output structure you need.

Comment: @MikeSchmidt - I've added section 2 in an attempt to explain my problem in more detail. For clarity, section 1 is what I have, section 3 is what I need. Could you please take a look one more time? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id_to_obj = {}
roots = []
def parse(row):
    pid, cid, lvl = row.parent_id, row.child_id, row.level
    if pid not in id_to_obj:
        # parent not created yet: create parent as root
        id_to_obj[pid] = {
            'id': pid, 'level': 0
        }
        roots.append(pid)

    # Get parent object
    parent = id_to_obj[pid]
    if not '_children' in parent:
        parent['_children'] = []

    # Create child object and add to parent's children list
    child = {
        'id': cid, 'level': lvl
    }
    parent['_children'].append(child)
    id_to_obj[cid] = child

df.sort_values(by='level').apply(parse, axis=1)

# Result
[id_to_obj[pid] for pid in roots]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing! This approach takes approx. 42 seconds for 740k rows.

Comment: @phi thank you so  much for this approach I was struggling with a similar issue, I have only done doubt that I have a huge data frame in which column name contains the date,how to produce that such JSON

Answer (score 4):

This hierarchical json has parent->child relationship. Therefore, I suggest you use `networkx` package to construct a graph `g` from the dateframe. From graph `g` create the desired json.

You need to `pip` install `networkx` following [this instruction](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html)

After that, do the following steps:

- import networkx as nx
- create the directed graph `g` using `from_pandas_edgelist`
- create a dictionary `d` with unique key on `parent_id` and `child_id`
  with values being as `level`
- assign `d` to nodes attributes `level` of graph `g`
- finally, call `nx.tree_data` on `g`

The code as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

#create the directed graph `g` using `from_pandas_edgelist`
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent_id', 'child_id', ['level'], 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())

#create a dictionary with unique key on `parent_id` and `child_id`
df1 = df.melt('level')
d = dict(zip(df1.value, df1.level))
root_id = df.loc[0, 'parent_id']
d[root_id] = 0  #set level of root to `0`

#assign `d` to nodes attributes `level` of graph `g`
nx.set_node_attributes(g, d, 'level')    #add `level` values to nodes of `g`

out = [nx.tree_data(g, root_id, {'id': 'id', 'children': '_children'})]

Out[119]:
[{'level': 0,
  'id': 125582,
  '_children': [{'level': 1, 'id': 214659},
   {'level': 1, 'id': 214633},
   {'level': 1,
    'id': 214263,
    '_children': [{'level': 2, 'id': 131673},
     {'level': 2, 'id': 125579},
     {'level': 2, 'id': 125578},
     {'level': 2,
      'id': 172670,
      '_children': [{'level': 3, 'id': 172669},
       {'level': 3, 'id': 174777},
       {'level': 3,
        'id': 207661,
        '_children': [{'level': 4, 'id': 216529},
         {'level': 4,
          'id': 223884,
          '_children': [{'level': 5,
            'id': 223885,
            '_children': [{'level': 6,
              'id': 229186,
              '_children': [{'level': 7, 'id': 219062},
               {'level': 7, 'id': 222243}]}]}]}]}]},
     {'level': 2,
      'id': 214266,
      '_children': [{'level': 3, 'id': 216675},
       {'level': 3, 'id': 216671}]}]}]}]
```

**Note**: the output above is the dictionary inside of list as your desired output. My solution output puts the key `level` in front of key `id`, but the hierarchical/structural of sub-dictionaries is the same as your desired output

---

On the other hand, if **you don't need the `level` values** in the desired output, just directly use the built-in `nx.tree_data` function to return the the output as follows

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent_id', 'child_id', ['level'], 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())

root_id = df.loc[0, 'parent_id']    
out = [nx.tree_data(g, root_id, {'id': 'id', 'children': '_children'})]

Out[168]:
[{'id': 125582,
  '_children': [{'id': 214659},
   {'id': 214633},
   {'id': 214263,
    '_children': [{'id': 131673},
     {'id': 125579},
     {'id': 125578},
     {'id': 172670,
      '_children': [{'id': 172669},
       {'id': 174777},
       {'id': 207661,
        '_children': [{'id': 216529},
         {'id': 223884,
          '_children': [{'id': 223885,
            '_children': [{'id': 229186,
              '_children': [{'id': 219062}, {'id': 222243}]}]}]}]}]},
     {'id': 214266, '_children': [{'id': 216675}, {'id': 216671}]}]}]}]
```

---

**Update**:

Use this modified function of `nx.tree_data` to overcome the restriction on single parent per child. Add this customized function to your code and call it instead of `nx.tree_data`

```
from itertools import chain

def tree_data_custom(G, root):
    id_ = 'id'
    children = '_children'
    def add_children(n, G):
        nbrs = G[n]
        if len(nbrs) == 0:
            return []
        children_ = []
        for child in nbrs:
            d = dict(chain(G.nodes[child].items(), [(id_, child)]))
            c = add_children(child, G)
            if c:
                d[children] = c
            children_.append(d)
        return children_

    data = dict(chain(G.nodes[root].items(), [(id_, root)]))    
    data[children] = add_children(root, G)
    return data
```

Instead of call `out = [nx.tree_data(g, root_id, {'id': 'id', 'children': '_children'})]`, just call `tree_data_custom` as follows

```
out =  [tree_data_custom(g, root_id)]
```

---

**Update 2**: Adding `name` column to dataframe

sample `df` where children has multiple parents

```
Out[258]:
    parent_id  child_id  level name
0      125582    214659      1   a1
1      125582    214633      1   a1
2      125582    214263      1   a1
3      214263    131673      2   a2
4      214263    125579      2   a2
5      214263    125578      2   a2
6      214263    172670      2   a2
7      214263    214266      2   a2
8      214266    216675      3   a3
9      214266    216671      3   a3
10     172670    172669      3   a3
11     172670    174777      3   a3
12     172670    207661      3   a3
13     207661    216529      4   a4
14     207661    223884      4   a4
15     223884    223885      5   a5
16     223885    229186      6   a6
17     229186    219062      7   a7
18     229186    222243      7   a7
19     222243    219187      8   a8
20     222243    245985      8   a8
21     222243    232393      8   a8
22     222243    247138      8   a8
23     222243    228848      8   a8
24     222243    228848      8   a8
25     222243    233920      8   a8
26     222243    233920      8   a8
27     222243    228113      8   a8
28     222243    233767      8   a8
29     222243    235407      8   a8
30     222243    237757      8   a8
31     222243    159091      8   a8
32     222243    159091      8   a8
33     222243    214832      8   a8
34     222243    253990      8   a8
35     222243    231610      8   a8
36     222243    231610      8   a8
37     222243    182323      8   a8
38     222243    242190      8   a8
39     222243    143580      8   a8
40     222243    242188      8   a8
41     222243    143581      8   a8
42     222243    242187      8   a8
43     222243    143582      8   a8
44     222243    242189      8   a8
45     222243    205877      8   a8
46     222243    242823      8   a8
47     222243    140979      8   a8
48     222243    237824      8   a8
49     222243    149933      8   a8
50     222243    149933      8   a8
51     222243    153625      8   a8
52     222243      8392      8   a8
53     222243    162085      8   a8
54     222243    162085      8   a8
55     222243    150691      8   a8
56     222243    147773      8   a8
57     222243    147773      8   a8
58     222243     61070      8   a8
59     222243     61070      8   a8
60     222243    204850      8   a8
61     222243    204850      8   a8
62      61070     46276      9   a9
63      61070     46276      9   a9
64      61070     46276      9   a9
65      61070     46276      9   a9
66     143580    159911      9   a9
67     143580     38958      9   a9
68     182323    159911      9   a9
```

The change is minimal, you only need to modify the step create dictionaries for nodes attributes of `g`. Currently, we only add attribute `level` to `g`. Now, we need to create another dictionary for `name` and add it to the new attribute `name` of nodes of `g`

```
#create the directed graph `g` using `from_pandas_edgelist`. 
#You don't need `[level]` in this step
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent_id', 'child_id', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

#create a dictionary with unique key on `parent_id` and `child_id`
#`melt` keep 2 columns 'level', 'name' instead of one column 'level'
#dictionary `d_level` for attribute `level` of `g's` nodes
#dictionary `d_name` for attribute `level` of `g's` nodes
df1 = df.melt(['level', 'name'])
d_level = dict(zip(df1.value, df1.level))
d_name = dict(zip(df1.value, df1.name))
root_id = df.loc[0, 'parent_id']
d_level[root_id] = 0  #set `level` of root to `0`

#assign `d_level` to nodes attributes `level` of graph `g` and `d_name` for `name`
nx.set_node_attributes(g, d_level, 'level')    #add `level` values to nodes of `g`
nx.set_node_attributes(g, d_name, 'name')    #add `name` values to nodes of `g`

#use customize `tree_data_custom` defined previously
out = [tree_data_custom(g, root_id)]
```

If you adding many more columns to each row, it is better to create a single dictionary for all columns and apply one time to nodes of `g` as follows

```
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent_id', 'child_id', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

df1 = df.melt(['level', 'name'])
#this single dictionary to create both `level` and `name` attributes of nodes of `g`
d = {v: {'level': l, 'name': n} for v,l,n in zip(df1.value, df1.level, df1.name)}
root_id = df.loc[0, 'parent_id']
d[root_id]['level'] = 0  #set level of root to `0`

nx.set_node_attributes(g, d)    #a single add for both attributes `level`, `name`

out = [tree_data_custom(g, root_id)]
```

Output

```
Out[260]:
[{'level': 0,
  'name': 'a1',
  'id': 125582,
  '_children': [{'level': 1, 'name': 'a1', 'id': 214659},
   {'level': 1, 'name': 'a1', 'id': 214633},
   {'level': 1,
    'name': 'a1',
    'id': 214263,
    '_children': [{'level': 2, 'name': 'a2', 'id': 131673},
     {'level': 2, 'name': 'a2', 'id': 125579},
     {'level': 2, 'name': 'a2', 'id': 125578},
     {'level': 2,
      'name': 'a2',
      'id': 172670,
      '_children': [{'level': 3, 'name': 'a3', 'id': 172669},
       {'level': 3, 'name': 'a3', 'id': 174777},
       {'level': 3,
        'name': 'a3',
        'id': 207661,
        '_children': [{'level': 4, 'name': 'a4', 'id': 216529},
         {'level': 4,
          'name': 'a4',
          'id': 223884,
          '_children': [{'level': 5,
            'name': 'a5',
            'id': 223885,
            '_children': [{'level': 6,
              'name': 'a6',
              'id': 229186,
              '_children': [{'level': 7, 'name': 'a7', 'id': 219062},
               {'level': 7,
                'name': 'a7',
                'id': 222243,
                '_children': [{'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 219187},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 245985},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 232393},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 247138},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 228848},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 233920},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 228113},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 233767},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 235407},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 237757},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 159091},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 214832},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 253990},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 231610},
                 {'level': 8,
                  'name': 'a8',
                  'id': 182323,
                  '_children': [{'level': 9, 'name': 'a9', 'id': 159911}]},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 242190},
                 {'level': 8,
                  'name': 'a8',
                  'id': 143580,
                  '_children': [{'level': 9, 'name': 'a9', 'id': 159911},
                   {'level': 9, 'name': 'a9', 'id': 38958}]},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 242188},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 143581},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 242187},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 143582},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 242189},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 205877},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 242823},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 140979},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 237824},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 149933},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 153625},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 8392},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 162085},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 150691},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 147773},
                 {'level': 8,
                  'name': 'a8',
                  'id': 61070,
                  '_children': [{'level': 9, 'name': 'a9', 'id': 46276}]},
                 {'level': 8, 'name': 'a8', 'id': 204850}]}]}]}]}]}]},
     {'level': 2,
      'name': 'a2',
      'id': 214266,
      '_children': [{'level': 3, 'name': 'a3', 'id': 216675},
       {'level': 3, 'name': 'a3', 'id': 216671}]}]}]}]
```

---

**Update 3**:  **handle columns `parent_name` and `child_name`**

You need to melt at once 4 columns `parent_name`, `child_name`, `parent_id`, `parent_id`. It is functionality of `wide_to_long`

```
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent_id', 'child_id', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

df1 = df.rename(lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1]), axis=1)
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df1.reset_index(), stubnames=['id', 'name'],
                i='index', j='type', suffix='\w+', sep='_')
d = {v: {'level': l, 'name': n} for v,l,n in zip(df1.id, df1.level, df1.name)}
root_id = df.loc[0, 'parent_id']
d[root_id]['level'] = 0

nx.set_node_attributes(g, d)
out = [tree_data_custom(g, root_id)] 

Out[91]:
[{'level': 0,
  'name': 'word1',
  'id': 125582,
  '_children': [{'level': 1, 'name': 'word6', 'id': 214659},
   {'level': 1, 'name': 'word7', 'id': 214633},
   {'level': 1,
    'name': 'word2',
    'id': 214263,
    '_children': [{'level': 2, 'name': 'word8', 'id': 131673},
     {'level': 2, 'name': 'word9', 'id': 125579},
     {'level': 2, 'name': 'word10', 'id': 125578},
     {'level': 2,
      'name': 'word4',
      'id': 172670,
      '_children': [{'level': 3, 'name': 'word13', 'id': 172669},
       {'level': 3, 'name': 'word14', 'id': 174777},
       {'level': 3,
        'name': 'word5',
        'id': 207661,
        '_children': [{'level': 4, 'name': 'word15', 'id': 216529},
         {'level': 4,
          'name': 'word16',
          'id': 223884,
          '_children': [{'level': 5,
            'name': 'word17',
            'id': 223885,
            '_children': [{'level': 6,
              'name': 'word18',
              'id': 229186,
              '_children': [{'level': 7, 'name': 'word19', 'id': 219062},
               {'level': 7, 'name': 'word20', 'id': 222243}]}]}]}]}]},
     {'level': 2,
      'name': 'word3',
      'id': 214266,
      '_children': [{'level': 3, 'name': 'word11', 'id': 216675},
       {'level': 3, 'name': 'word12', 'id': 216671}]}]}]}]
```

Comment: Would your first solution performance wise be more efficient than James’s recursive solution when I am dealing with 1 million rows?

Comment: @dunkubok: Honestly, I don't know. I have never tried `networkx` on that big of dataset. It would be great if you try both and share the timing on your real dataset. Perhaps, the benchmark on several different ops from this link https://www.timlrx.com/2019/05/05/benchmark-of-popular-graph-network-packages/ , the result of `pokec, 1.6m nodes, 30.6m edges` dataset would give you a glimpse on networkx performance.

Comment: Hi Andy, your first solution is throwing an error on row 70 in my DataFrame. Any idea why? https://pastebin.com/Gw4VRQn9

Comment: It is supposed to add id `159911` to id `182323`, but it seems to be failing: https://i.imgur.com/3MnhRZp.png

Comment: @dunkubok: `159911` has 2 parents which are `143580` and `182323`. `nx.tree_data` limits each child has only one parent. Try to use the modified function `tree_data_custom` to see it works for you. I edited answer to add `tree_data_custom` function

Comment: is `chain` an itertools function?

Comment: oh yeah, you need ` from itertools import chain` :)

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Performance-wise it appears to be ok. 10 seconds for 800k records

Comment: Wow, that is pretty good speed. It is much better than I expect :)

Comment: Ok, confirmed. 11 seconds for 740k rows.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer. This helped me a lot!

Comment: How can I pass extra DataFrame columns to the json? Let’s say I want to add field “Name” to each row?

Comment: @dunkubok: you just need to create a new dictionary for the new column and assign it to the new attribute `name` of nodes of the graph `g`. I edited the answer to show it. compare the new codes and the old codes, you will know how to add more columns if later on you want to add further more columns.

Comment: I added another way to create a single dictionary to add multiple columns values to the json. Just pick the one you feel like :)

Comment: Would this also work with extra columns, for example: `parent_name` and `child_name`, similar to `parent_id` and `child_id`?

Comment: If relationship of `parent_name` and `child_name` to `parent_id` and `child_id` in each row is the same as the `level` colum, you just need to add 2 more attributes `parent_name` and `child_name` to `g` as  I shown with column `name`. However, if the relationship/layout are different, I can't answer without seeing example data and desired output.

Comment: how does the json look like with the new `parent_id` and `child_id`? could you give an example json from the pastebin link input above?

Comment: I've created INPUT + OUTPUT example here: https://pastebin.com/b4ycEcuj
Thanks again!

Comment: @dunkubok: it requires more pre-processing to handle `parent_name` and `child_name`. I added `update 3` to show how it is done. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Hi Andy - There seems to be a problem in the current algorithm. Here is an example: https://pastebin.com/cn4VMHv6. There are many records where the levels don't correspond with the input data. In this case, there are children with level 9 inside parent on level 11. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Hi Andy, will this work multiple root nodes ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a pandas one-liner, but here's a recursive function that should do the trick.

```python
import json

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{"parent_id": 125582, "child_id": 214659, "level": 1}, {"parent_id": 125582, "child_id": 214633, "level": 1},
     {"parent_id": 125582, "child_id": 214263, "level": 1}, {"parent_id": 214263, "child_id": 131673, "level": 2},
     {"parent_id": 214263, "child_id": 125579, "level": 2}, {"parent_id": 214263, "child_id": 125578, "level": 2},
     {"parent_id": 214263, "child_id": 172670, "level": 2}, {"parent_id": 214263, "child_id": 214266, "level": 2},
     {"parent_id": 214266, "child_id": 216675, "level": 3}, {"parent_id": 214266, "child_id": 216671, "level": 3},
     {"parent_id": 172670, "child_id": 172669, "level": 3}, {"parent_id": 172670, "child_id": 174777, "level": 3},
     {"parent_id": 172670, "child_id": 207661, "level": 3}, {"parent_id": 207661, "child_id": 216529, "level": 4},
     {"parent_id": 207661, "child_id": 223884, "level": 4}, {"parent_id": 223884, "child_id": 223885, "level": 5},
     {"parent_id": 223885, "child_id": 229186, "level": 6}, {"parent_id": 229186, "child_id": 219062, "level": 7},
     {"parent_id": 229186, "child_id": 222243, "level": 7}]
)


def recurse(parent_id, level):
    # create the base result
    result = {"id": int(parent_id), "level": int(level)}

    # get all of the children of this parent, one level below this one
    children = df[(df.parent_id == parent_id) & (df["level"] == level + 1)]

    # if there are no such children, then return without a _children key
    if children.empty:
        return result

    # otherwise, recurse on each child_id
    result["_children"] = [recurse(child_id, level + 1) for child_id in sorted(children.child_id.unique())]

    return result


# start at an implicit level 0
tree = [recurse(parent_id, 0) for parent_id in sorted(df[df["level"] == 1].parent_id.unique())]

# convert to JSON
print(json.dumps(tree, indent=3, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: This code returns 3 root elements with the same id: https://i.imgur.com/aZPsmSu.png
Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I added a fix, but performance testing suggests it's much too slow for the scale you're talking about.